# How to use property binding with a string in Angular?

Tags: angular

Using interpolation to set a property works with this code:

```
This work for me.
<span *ngFor="let car of Car; let i = index;" >
<img src="car/{{car.id}}">
</span>
```

but it does not work using **`property binding`** like this:

```
<span *ngFor="let car of Car; let i = index;" >
<img [src]="car/car.id">
</span>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following syntax for property binding:

```
[src]="'car/' + car.id"
```

Comment: Interpolation is not used for property binding since it is already implied.

Comment: @蒋建雨 - Feel free to mark the answer as accepted (with the green check mark) if it provides a solution to your question.